# How prove this inequality $a^2+b^2+c^2+8(ab+bc+ac)+3-10(a+b+c)\ge 0$

Tags: inequality

let $a,b,c\ge 0$,and such $abc=1$,show that

> $$a^2+b^2+c^2+8(ab+bc+ac)+3-10(a+b+c)\ge 0$$

**My solution: Without loss of generality,assume that**

> $a=\max{(a,b,c)}$, since $abc=1$,we have
>   $a\ge 1$,
>
> we will show that
>   $$f(a,b,c)\ge f(a,t,t)\ge 0, t=\sqrt{bc},0<t\le 1$$
>
> since $$f(a,b,c)-f(a,t,t)=(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2[(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2+8a-10]$$
>   then equivalent to
>   $$(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2+8a\ge 10$$
>   which is true because 
>   $$(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2+8a\ge 4\sqrt{bc}+8a=4(a+\sqrt{bc})+4a\ge 8\sqrt{a\sqrt{bc}}+4a=8\sqrt[4]{a}+4a\ge 12$$

Now,since $a=\dfrac{1}{t^2}$,we have
$$f(a,t,t)=f(\dfrac{1}{t^2},t,t)=\dfrac{(10t^4-7t^2+2t+1)(t-1)^2}{t^4}$$
which is clearly nonnegative because

> $$10t^4-7t^2+2t+1=(3t^2-1)^2+t(1-t)+t^4+t>0$$

Have other nice methods? Thank you

Comment: Please add the domain of a,b,c. I guess they are real numbers but it may be misleading not to write the domain.

Comment: Have a look at here(all the answers):http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167855/proving-fracaba23b2-fraccbb23c2-fracacc23a2-le-frac3?rq=1

Comment: No,This is not same problem,and this problem is hard.

Comment: I'd try Newton's identities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^2+\dfrac8x + 1 - 10x + 16 \log x$ for $x > 0$.
Then the given inequality is $f(a)+f(b)+f(c) \ge 0$, and it is sufficient to show $f(x) \ge 0$.

We note $f'(x) = \dfrac{2(x-2)^2 (x-1)}{x^2}$.
Thus for $x < 1, f'(x)<0$ and for $x > 1, f'(x) \ge 0$.  Hence $\forall x >0, \; f(x) \ge f(1) = 0$.

Comment: where does the 16 lnx came from thank you

Comment: @GregoriusWillson When facing the constraint $abc=1$, a good way to separate the variables is by taking logs.  Thus adding $k\cdot \log x$ to $f(x)$ will not change anything, as on summing across $a, b, c$, it will disappear.  What is left is to choose $k$ wisely, so that $f(x)\geqslant 0$ in the domain of interest.  In this case we know equality is when $a=b=c=1$, so we choose $k$ s.t. $f'(1)=0$ and test for non-negativity...

Comment: thanks im just realizing it nice solution btw

Comment: but how if the roots of first derivative are not double rooted like for this case this is $(x-2)^2*(x-1)$ how if $\frac{(2(x-1)(x^2-29x+55))}{x^2}$

Comment: There is no general prescription here, in many cases this approach would lead to a simple proof - but not in all cases.  Maybe a more general approach (for 'separable' inequalities) would be to try Jensen / Karamata first, then tangent line or this one, then more complex approaches like substitutions or mixing variables if earlier approaches fail...

Comment: do u have email or any private chat because i would ask u something about problem i had

Comment: @GregoriusWillson Suggest you post separately if there's a different problem, i or someone else should help out.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, our inequality is a linear inequality of $v^2$, which says that

it's remains to prove the last inequality for an extremal value of $v^2$,

which happens for equality case of two variables.

Let $b=a$ and $c=\frac{1}{a^2}$.

Hence, we need to prove that 
$$(a-1)^2(10a^4-7a^2+2a+1)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.